# Ninject Garbage Collection

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, ninject

I am using Ninject in a n-tier application consisting of services, repositories, all wired up with the UnitOfWork pattern and Ninject. Further, I have different jobs executing in separate threads referencing those services and repositories.

Every now and again, seems at random times, I get an exception which crashes my console application executing the jobs. The exception is:

```
Application: Playground.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.NullReferenceException
Stack:
   at Ninject.Activation.Caching.GarbageCollectionCachePruner.PruneCacheIfGarbageCollectorHasRun(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(System.Object)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode, CleanupCode, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading._TimerCallback.PerformTimerCallback(System.Object)
```

As far as I understand this has something to do with the new Cache-and-Collection management in Ninject. However, I have not specified any Scopes for any Ninject bindins.

**EDIT:**  Code samples:

Here is some of the code used(I believe the critical part):

```
    public class DefaultUnitOfWork<TObjectContext> : Provider<ObjectContext>, IUnitOfWork, IServiceUnitOfWork
        where TObjectContext : ObjectContext, new()
      {
        public DefaultUnitOfWork(){
          _kernel = new CustomKernel(new CommonRepositoryModule(), new        ServiceModule(), (NinjectModule)kernel.Get<IAmApplicationSpecificModule>());
        }
    }
```

I did end up checking the source before some time for another issue that I had. Basically, previously there were multiple instances of the `kernel` being created and not disposed so in order to ovewrite this behaviour and dispose of them I implemented `IDisposable` and in the I called the `Dispose(bool disposing)` method on the kernel.

```
    public void Dispose()
    {
      if (_kernel != null) _kernel.Dispose(true); 
    }
```

I hope that those samples are handy.

**EDIT 2**

I found the issue and it was completely my fault. Because of some scoping and disposing issues that I had, I modified the code so I dispose in the above mentioned way Dispose(true). This was messing up the caching mechanisms of Ninject. I re-implemented most of the code and no problem. Thanks for the ideas, though.

Comment: It's really impossible to say anything without code.

Comment: OP: What @Daniel Hilgarth iis trying to say is can you post some excerpts of that source (from gitHub). Personally I'd recommend looking in the source yourself - it's tidy and you'll discover that the pruning stuff always gets initialized regardless of whether you're directly using it

Comment: It's most likely your threading, you probably have a thread that set an injected property or object to null, and ninject is now trying to remove it from it's cache.  Something along those lines, but I'm just taking a stab in the dark.

Comment: @Ruben: Eh, no. That's not what I am trying to say. I wanted to see his code. I am not interested in the Ninject code, because I assume it is not the problem.

Comment: @Ruben, I have posted some code in the edit above.

Comment: @Coding Gorilla, that was my first guess as well. However, it is very difficult to reproduce this error as it appears quite randomly. That lead me to believe also that it is probably something in the multithreading and timing. However, I think there must be something wrong with my object scoping as well.

Comment: @sTodorov I suspect that this is going to be an issue that takes a **lot** of time and `Debbuger.WriteLine()` calls to fix, I'm not sure that anyone here is going to be able to help you with it.

Comment: Question: This is not really related to your problem but I was wondering why do you need a different kernel for each unit of work? And which ninject version are you using?

Comment: @Daniel, no I don't think that I need. I re-implemented the whole thing without this extra Kernel. I am using 2.2

Comment: Could you show the provider model also and the modules in that you are using in this code so that we get the whole picture?

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth: Thanks for clarifying - I (clearly!) hadnt given it much thought!

Comment: This looks like a known Ninject 2.2 bug, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314554/bug-in-ninject. It appears to be fixed in Ninject 3